# How can I format two list?

Tags: python-2.7, format

I have a list likes:

```
y=['1997,05,22', '1997,05,21', '1997,05,20', '1997,05,19', '1997,05,16', '1997,05,15'........]
```

and I try using `.format` to change fotmat of list like:

```
[new Date(1997,05,22),new Date(1997,05,21),new Date(1997,05,20),...]
```

first I try

```
y2 = []
for i in y:
z = 'new Date({0},{1},{2})'.format(*i)
y2.append(z)
```

in order to get list like`[new Date(1997,05,22),...]` but output is like this :

```
['new Date(1,9,9)', 'new Date(1,9,9)', 'new Date(1,9,9)', 'new Date(1,9,9)', 'new Date(1,9,9)', 'new Date(1,9,9)']
```

any ideas? Thansk!

Comment: Why not just use `z = 'new Date({0})'.format(i)`? (remove the (`*`) splat operator)

Comment: it works!Thanks!